# Should one say "0.1 degree Celsius" or "0.1 degrees Celsius"?

Tags: word-usage

The value isn't exactly 1, it's a fraction. But 1 is the only number in the fraction. Should the word degree be singular or plural?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey How is containing a zero relevant? I just want to know why you pointed that out.

Comment: Your argument is that '1 is the only [numeral] in the fraction'. Michael is pointing out that the numeral status of 0 (zero) is every bit as pedigreed as that of 1 (or 2, 3 ...). _Every_ number other than one (and note that 'number' is to 'numeral' as 'word' is to 'letter')  takes plural agreement with units in usual usage. // To expand on Michael's last point, 'fractions' covers the formats decimals, common fractions, percentages, .... Confusingly, common fractions are often also referred to simply as 'fractions'.